# Using a List or Dictionary of Strings to create a new column based on an existing column within a Data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a set of values in a column within my dataframe.  There is no particular pattern for the values and is random for most cases, but I would like set up my own dictionary or list so if the string contains these values I can create a new column to match these keywords.  I come from an R background so what I did before was create a for loop unpacking the a list with grepl.

Let's say I have the Dictionary:

my_dict:

```
my_dict = {"BC": "Vancouver", "AB": "Calgary", "SK": ["Regina","Saskatoon"], "MB": ["Winnipeg","Brandon"], "ON":["Toronto","Ottawa"]}
```

Essentially, what I want is that if the string is ever matched, then use the Key of the dictionary.  Also if their happens to no match or the Key is not listed in the dictionary, then 'Other' would be inputted.  This is what I would like to see.

df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Jordan","Paul","Adrian","Sarah","Becky","Shawn"], "City":["Vancouver - Lower Mainland","Calgary/Lethbridge","Regina / Moose Jaw","Brandon","Ottawa_Hamilton","Montreal"],
                "Province_Fixed": ["BC","AB","SK","MB","ON","Other"]})
```

The "Provinced_Fixed" column would be the output.  I would like to know which method would be the best way to approach this problem.  I just gave a dictionary for the sake of the question, it does not need to be done in this way.
Thanks so much! I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lopp by dictionary values and create new column with all rows with match by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), also for `list`s is necessary join values to one string by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    pat = '|'.join(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v
    df.loc[df['City'].str.contains(pat) , 'new'] = k

df['new'] = df['new'].fillna('Other')
print (df)
     Name                        City Province_Fixed    new
0  Jordan  Vancouver - Lower Mainland             BC     BC
1    Paul          Calgary/Lethbridge             AB     AB
2  Adrian          Regina / Moose Jaw             SK     SK
3   Sarah                     Brandon             MB     MB
4   Becky             Ottawa_Hamilton             ON     ON
5   Shawn                    Montreal          Other  Other
```